# Can i change the default behaviour of wordpress category list to checkboxes

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, wordpress

i want the list in the left side to have checkboxes so that the visitor can navigate much easily just like the way amazon.com does it.

this is how it is now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMiuD.jpg
i want it to be something like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jHsW.jpg

Comment: FYI, there is a stack site dedicated to wordpress: wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

if you want to modify wordpress default behaviour [The Wordpress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/) will be your best friend.

Simply type the name of the function you want to modify in the search box and you will see how it works and how you can extend it.

Here is a link for your particular Problem, [WP_LIST_CATEGORIES()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

Comment: i just want to make them act like a group of checkboxes to make the posts selection narrow as the user proceeds